# Find CURRENTLY selected <option> with XPath

Tags: dom, xpath

What's the correct XPath syntax to check if an `option` element is ***currently*** selected, or just to get the selected `option` element from a `select` element, on an open page with which the user, and JavaScript, may have interacted? Is this even possible with XPath, or does it lack the ability to look at DOM properties?

I can't find any documentation on this, and have (speculatively) tried:

- `//option[@selected=true]`
- `//option[@selected="selected"]`
- `//option[@selected]`

but none of these work; they simply don't match any elements.

*(In case it matters, I've tried this both using the `$x` function in the Chrome developer console, and using the `find_elements_by_xpath` method in Selenium for Python.)*

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Short answer: it's not possible.

Longer answer: XPath can look at HTML attributes, but it can't look at DOM properties. Selecting an `<option>` element in a `<select>` changes the `selected` *property* of the `<option>` to `true`, and also changes the `value` property of its parent `<select>` element, but it doesn't affect the attributes of either, so it is invisible to XPath.

To find `<option>` elements that have the `selected` attribute set, which is often how a page author might determine which option is initially selected, you can use `//option[@selected]`. But this *does not* find the *currently* selected `<option>`; changes that the user makes to the selection are invisible to XPath. There's no guarantee it will even find the *initially* selected option, since it's possible that the page author didn't put the `selected` attribute on *any* elements and either let the browser select the first option by default or had some JavaScript select the initial option via the `selected` *property*.

The multiple [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17132439/1709587) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17992485/1709587) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27642105/1709587) [claiming](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15769357/1709587) that a selector like `//option[@selected]` can detect selection changes made by the user after the page loads are simply completely wrong.

Of course, if you're able to use *CSS* selectors instead of XPath selectors, then [`option:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) will do the job.

Comment: It seemed that `//option[@selected]` was working at first as I had `<option value="0" selected>Select Something</option>`, but I noticed that if I use the same XPath to search for a second dropdown in the same page, the first dropdown was always selected.. `option:checked` is what saved the day!

Answer (score 6):

The problem could be the `"` (double quotes).

`//select/option[@selected='selected']` - Will match the selected option, i am using this successfully.

`//select/option[@selected='selected' and @value='specific value']` - Will only match the selected option if it has a 'specific value', i'm also using this.

If you are still having trouble, it could be an entirely different problem, perhaps there is no option node.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Besides the main way in which this answer is wrong, a secondary bit of wrongness is the suggestion that quoting string expressions in my XPath with single instead of double quotes could change its behaviour. This is false, even in the oldest versions of XPath. Per [the original spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-Introduction), *"Within expressions, literal strings are delimited by single or double quotation marks"*.

Comment: What is the main way in which this answer is wrong?

Comment: It doesn't work at all. `//select/option[@selected='selected']` will not match the currently selected option; it will match any option that has the `selected` attribute set to the string `"selected"`. That's not even guaranteed to be the *initially* selected option (since the mere *presence* of the `selected` attribute marks an `option` as initially selected; it doesn't matter what its value is), let alone the currently selected one (since which option is *currently* selected is completely independent of the presence or value of the `selected` attribute).

Comment: it works for me, of course the option has to have the attribute "selected" with value "selected". Upvote!

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use a knowledge from @Mark's answer and account that. Let's just find a node which HAS desired attribute:

```
tree.xpath('//select/option[@selected]/text()')[0].strip()
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried **"//option[@selected='']** and it  has worked for me.
it is able to highlight the selected option within Page objects model.

Answer (score -2):

I would try `//option[@selected='true']`

i.e. `driver.findElements(By.xpath("//option[@selected='true']")).getText();`