# How to get the text of the selected option using Selenium 2 PHPUnit

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit

I am trying to get the text "High Gloss Paper Sticker" in my Selenium program but all my program can do is to get the text of all options. Any suggestions or syntaxes that might help me get this through would be appreciated.

```html
<select id="attr1" class="op_select" name="attr1">
  
  <option value="16506">Matte Paper Sticker</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="13187">High Gloss Paper Sticker</option>
  <option value="16507">High Gloss Vinyl Sticker</option>

</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn [Xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769282/find-currently-selected-option-with-xpath) and you will be fine.

```
public IWebElement Attr1 {
     get { 
        return this.browser.FindElement(By.XPath(@"//select[@id='attr1']/option[@selected='selected']")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`id` is fastest way to find the element.

This is just an example

`$id_select_box = $this->webDriver->findElement(\WebDriverBy::id('select_box'));
$selected_option = new \WebDriverSelect($id_select_box);
$this->assertEquals("String", $selected_option->getFirstSelectedOption()->getText());`